# Which data structure to use for storing a paragraph?

Tags: data-structures

Recently an interviewer asked me 
1. Which data structure should be used if you need store a paragraph, traverse it later and find a word ? 
2. Which data structure to use if you can also add, edit or delete words in that paragraph ?

Can someone help me with the answer ?
And if possible can someone also post similar questions with logical answers on data structures as am preparing for interviews.

Comment: You might want to look at [ropes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) and [gap buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). A trie a tree whose nodes store unique combinations of letters (prefixes), and whose edges point to combinations of letters following those prefixes (suffixes). Tries can be built from text documents to give O(L) search, insertion, and deletion time (L is length of word you are searching for, adding, or deleting). Tries are used commonly in autocomplete and document search algorithms.

Comment: Since we want to find whole words, I would add that you need to define a special character to tag the end of a word. For instance, if we chose `$`, when inserting the word `bubble` in the trie, we would insert `bubble$` instead. Later if we try to see if we find the word `bubl` we would look for `bubl$` and wouldn't find a match. Another solution is to tag the leaves of the trie

Comment: Not necessarily. You could always just make sure to end all branches with null nodes, e.g. if the tree had cat and cats in it, there would be a null child node after the t and the s, but not the a.